# Two recyclerView and one onClick showing the content of the clicked element of the respective recyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, onclick

**Problem**
In my acitvity i have two recyclerViews showing popular movies and top rated movies respectively.
When I click on a movie in a recyclerView, that movie is sent to an activity showing its details.
I go back to the home and if I click on a movie of another recyclerView, the previously clicked movie is shown.
I need to show the details of any clicked movie in any recyclerView.

I have a single viewHolder (MovieViewHolder)

```
 public class MovieViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    //Widgets
    TextView title, rating;
    ImageView imageView;

    //Click listener
    OnMovieListener onMovieListener ;

    public MovieViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView, OnMovieListener onMovieListener) {
        super(itemView);

        this.onMovieListener = onMovieListener;

        title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.movie_title);
        imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.movie_img);
        rating = itemView.findViewById(R.id.rating_bar);

        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        onMovieListener.onMovieClick(getAdapterPosition());

    }
```

An interface

```
public interface OnMovieListener {

    void onMovieClick(int position);
    void onCategoryClick(String category);


}
```

This two Adapter:
This for popular movies

```
public class MovieRecyclerView extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    private List<MovieModel> mMovies;
    private final OnMovieListener onMovieListener;


    public MovieRecyclerView(OnMovieListener onMovieListener) {
        this.onMovieListener = onMovieListener;

    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.movie_item,
                parent, false);


        return new MovieViewHolder(view, onMovieListener);

    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        ((MovieViewHolder) holder).title.setText(mMovies.get(position).getTitle());
        ((MovieViewHolder) holder).rating.setText(String.valueOf((float) (mMovies.get(position).getVote_average())));

        //ImageView: Using Glide Library
        Glide.with(holder.itemView.getContext())
                .load("https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/"
                        + mMovies.get(position).getPoster_path())
                .into(((MovieViewHolder) holder).imageView);


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if (mMovies != null) {
            return mMovies.size();
        }
        return 0;
    }

    public void setmMovies(List<MovieModel> mMovies) {
        this.mMovies = mMovies;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    //Getting the id of the movie clicked
    public MovieModel getSelectedMovie(int position) {
        if (mMovies != null) {
            if (mMovies.size() > 0) {
                return mMovies.get(position);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

This for top_rated

```
public class MovieLatestRecyclerView extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    private List<MovieModel> mMoviesLatest;
    private OnMovieListener onMovieListener;

    public MovieLatestRecyclerView(OnMovieListener onMovieListener) {
        this.onMovieListener = onMovieListener;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
       View  view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.movie_item,
                parent, false);
        return new MovieViewHolder(view, onMovieListener);

    }



    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        ((MovieViewHolder)holder).title.setText(mMoviesLatest.get(position).getTitle());
        ((MovieViewHolder)holder).rating.setText(String.valueOf((float) (mMoviesLatest.get(position).getVote_average())));

        //ImageView: Using Glide Library
        Glide.with(holder.itemView.getContext())
                .load("https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/"
                        + mMoviesLatest.get(position).getPoster_path())
                .into(((MovieViewHolder)holder).imageView);

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if(mMoviesLatest != null) {
            return mMoviesLatest.size();
        }
        return 0;
    }

    public void setmMoviesLatest(List<MovieModel> mMoviesLatest) {
        this.mMoviesLatest = mMoviesLatest;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    //Getting the id of the movie clicked
    public MovieModel getSelectedMovie(int position){
        if(mMoviesLatest != null){
            if(mMoviesLatest.size() > 0){
                return mMoviesLatest.get(position);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

In MainActivity i configure the recyclerViews with this method

```
 private void ConfigureRecyclerView() {
        movieRecyclerViewAdapter = new MovieRecyclerView(this);
        movieLatestRecyclerViewAdapter = new MovieLatestRecyclerView(this);

        recyclerView_popular.setAdapter(movieRecyclerViewAdapter);
        recyclerView_popular.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));

        recyclerView_latest.setAdapter(movieLatestRecyclerViewAdapter);
        recyclerView_latest.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));

        //RecyclerView Pagination
        //Loading next page of api response
        recyclerView_popular.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
                if (!recyclerView.canScrollVertically(1)) {
                    //Here we need to display the next search result
                    movieListViewModel.searchNextPage();
                }
            }
        });
        recyclerView_latest.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
                if (!recyclerView.canScrollVertically(1)) {
                    //Here we need to display the next search result
                    movieListViewModel.searchNextPage();
                }
            }
        });

    }
```

And i use this for passing the selected movie to another activity

```
 @Override
    public void onMovieClick(int position) {
        //WE don't need position of the movie in recyclerView
        // We need the ID of the movie in order to get all it's details
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MovieDetails.class);


            intent.putExtra("movie", movieRecyclerViewAdapter.getSelectedMovie(position));
            startActivity(intent);


    }
```

Whoever you are reading my question I thank you for your time and I apologize for the certain banality and length.

Comment: So what's specifically your question? do you face any issues?

Comment: If I have two recyclerView "Popular" and "Top Rated", if the first movie I click is in Popular, when I click on a movie in Top Rated it shows me the movie I clicked first in "Popular".

Answer (score 0):

At this line:

```
intent.putExtra("movie", movieRecyclerViewAdapter.getSelectedMovie(position));
```

You are getting a movie from `movieRecyclerViewAdapter`. This adapter is only used with the 'Popular' movie recycler view.

`onMovieClick` is used for both the 'Popular' and the 'Top Rated' recycler views. So, clicking an item from 'Top Rated' will attempt to use an item from 'Popular'.

To fix this, a click from 'Top Rated' should not attempt to get an item from `movieRecyclerViewAdapter`.

You could do something like change `onMovieClick(int position)` to `onMovieClick(MovieModel movie)`, so you don't have to worry about knowing which adapter to get the movie from.